# Adding dynamic style to the progress bar using ng-style

Tags: html, css, angularjs, progress-bar

what i need:

```
<progress ng-style={background-color: variable } ></progress>
```

but for it to work in chrome and firefox the style should be given as

```
progress::-webkit-progress-bar{
   background-color: red;
}                                     //chrome

progress::-moz-progress-bar {  
    background-color: red;
}                                     //firefox
```

where as setting the ng-style for progress::-webkit-progress-bar is not possible. so how do i dynamically give the styling through ng-style..any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining classes for progress bar background-color variations, so that you can add all the browser prefixes, and add your variable by interpolating it in the class attribute?

E.g. CSS classes

```
.progress-red::-webkit-progress-bar,
.progress-red::-moz-progress-bar{
    background-color: red;
}

.progress-blue::-webkit-progress-bar,
.progress-blue::-moz-progress-bar{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And your HTML

```
<progress class="progress-{{variable}}"></progress>
```

Alternatively, you could use a progress bar library such as [Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#progressbar) or define your own as [exemplified in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/570vpup8/)